# Syntax error on apostrophe

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, syntax-error

the apostrophe at the end of 'you answered: ' is registering as a syntax error, not sure why as it is just ending the string.
I don't know what to try

```
print('You got the following questions wrong:'
                    'Question' , incorrectnum[i] , incorrect_Q[i]
                    'You answered:' , incorrect_A[i]
                    'The correct answer was:' , correct_answers[int(incorrectnum[i])])
```

Comment: `wrong:''Question` and missing commas everywhere

Comment: The error is after `wrong:` you need either a `,` or `+` to concatenate the text

Comment: Please update your question with the full text of the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing commas in the arguments for the `print()` function. You can use the following:

```
print('You got the following questions wrong:',
                'Question' , incorrectnum[i] , incorrect_Q[i],
                'You answered:' , incorrect_A[i],
                'The correct answer was:', correct_answers[int(incorrectnum[i])])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add commas between EVERY string/variable. It should look like this:

```
print('You got the following questions wrong:',
                'Question', incorrectnum[i], incorrect_Q[i],
                'You answered:', incorrect_A[i],
                'The correct answer was:', correct_answers[int(incorrectnum[i])])
```

You should next time read the syntax error properly, as it usually explains what/where the error is.